# Get list of scanners on the network

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I need to get a list of scanners on the network that aren't necessarily installed on the machine the program is running from. I am unsure of how to do this and have searched StackOverflow to no avail.

*Background*

I need to get a list of scanners on the network along with their details like device id, ip address, name, etc. So that I can communicate with them using some kind of TWAIN solution. I need to be able to tell the networked scanner where to save the scan depending on the application workflow.

**TLDR**

Using C#, how do I get a list of all the scanners on the network (installed on the local machine or not)?

**Clarification**

The scanners are on the network connected by *ethernet* to the router. They are *not* connected to the server the application is running on. These are the only scanners I am interested in getting a list of.

Comment: Are these network-capable scanners with Ethernet connections on the scanners, or locally connected to PCs that are on the network?

Comment: Ethernet connections on the scanner

Comment: Given an IP address, do you already have a method to ping it to see if a scanner is there?  If so, the question becomes "how to scan all IP addresses on the local network"? or are you asking how to detect a scanner at a given IP address?

Comment: I guess if I know the ip address, how would I go about detecting that it is a scanner at the ip address vs some other device? But ideally, I would like my application to be able to discover all the scanners on the network first.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get a list of scanners. it is depending on the scanner device type some scanners are used USB and not Ethernet. If you are sure that the wished scanners are connect to the computer by using network cable then you can search for example by ping and send some header text according to the scanner API.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use "Select * from Win32_PnPEntity".
But you would have to figure out the condition on which to filter the scanners on.

Comment: The device which he means might be not PNP the scanner is connect with network cabel.